# Append child and sort dynamic list

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, mapbox-gl

I have a map whose whose `features` change depending on the map extent.  The function `renderListings` creates an element `item` for each feature and then adds all the items to `listingEl` every time the map changes.  So far that is working fine.

The `innerHTML` of each `item` is based on a property of the feature - `prop.code`, which is a string of text.  At this point the function appends items in an unordered way, not alphabetically.

I have tried adding `.sort()` to `listingEl.appendChild(item).sort()` but then only *one* item appears in the list and all of the others disappear.

How would one go about alphabetically appending children by the feature property `prop.code` in javascript?

```
var listingEl = document.getElementById('feature-listing');


function renderListings(features) {
    // Clear any existing listings
    listingEl.innerHTML = '';
    if (features.length) {
        features.forEach(function(feature) {
            var prop = feature.properties;
            var item = document.createElement('a');
            item.target = '_blank';
            item.innerHTML = '<div style ="display:inline;">   ' + prop.code + ' </div>' 


            listingEl.appendChild(item);

        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just order the features before adding them to the list.

```
var listingEl = document.getElementById('feature-listing');

function renderListingsSorted(features) {
    var sortedFeatures = sortFeaturesByCode(features);
    renderListings(sortedFeatures);
}

function sortFeaturesByCode(features) {
    return features.sort(function(f1, f2){
        var code1 = f1.properties.code;
        var code2 = f2.properties.code;
        return code1.localeCompare(code2);
    });
}

function renderListings(features) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work because the `features` that go into `renderListings()` remain unsorted

Comment: Do you mean the `sortFeaturesByCode` function doesn't actually sort the features?

Comment: right, the listings are not being sorted because everything should be in the `renderListings()` function, if that's possible

Comment: [It does work for me](https://jsbin.com/kofarisodo/1/edit?js,console). Can you share what a feature looks like?

Comment: Can't you just pass the sorted features to the renderListings() function?